# Regular expressions and equality

Tags: regular-expressions

Is the equality true or false?

$(r^*s^*)=(r+s)^*$

My Approach:

Assume the alphabet used is {0,1}$^*$

Equality is false:

If r = 0 and s = 1

Then if    0101 $∈$ $(0 + 1)^*$ this is true because $(0 + 1)^*$ contains all strings that contain 0 or 1

But 0101 $∉$ $(0^*1^*)$ because this contains all 0s followed by all 1s so 0101 is not a member of this set by this definition.

Also $(0^*1^*)$ $⊂$ $(0 + 1)^*$ but $(0 + 1)^*$ $⊄$ $(0^*1^*)$

Comment: You have a correct example showing that $(r^*s^*)$ need not equal $(r+s)^*$. It is true in general that $(r^*s^*)\subseteq(r+s)^*$, not just in your example.

Comment: So this proof would work fine to answer this question correct?

Comment: Yes: you’ve correctly said that the equality is not true in general, and you’ve given a correct counterexample. That’s exactly what’s wanted here.

Comment: Alright, was just making sure thanks for the clarification was just wondering.

Comment: You’re welcome.