# Regular Expression Equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-expressions

I've seen the other post ([Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194770/regular-expressions-and-equality)) for (b), but I wasn't sure if the same logic applies if you use the assumption below. I also saw this post ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265193/regular-expression-does-kleene-star-have-a-distributive-property)) for a but again wasn't sure if the assumption might have any effect.

If L(R) ⊆ L(S),

a) R$^*$ + S$^*$ ≡ (R+S)$^*$

b) R$^*$S$^*$ ≡ (RS)$^*$

I think that (a) is true since R is a subset of S, R + S is always in S, thus S$^*$ must include R$^*$ + S$^*$. For (b) I think it is false but I cannot seem to justify it formally due to the assumption. So am I right in saying that a is true and b is false? If so how do I go about justifying that?

Answer (score 1):

(b) is false. Take $R = \emptyset$ and $S = a$, where $a$ is a letter. Then $R \subseteq S$, $R^* = 1$, $R^*S^* = a^*$, but $(RS)^* = \emptyset^* = 1$.